# Parse string in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, substring

I'm doing `for-each` loop in the XSLT and it's returning me a long string. What I want to do is parse the string .

Here's the code.

```
<xsl:for-each select="/CAudioFile/CRI/PrivateData/PrivateData/DictionaryEntry">
    <xsl:value-of select="Value" />
</xsl:for-each>
```

This is the string it's returning:

```
9702195481, 31201(CCC AGENT)09999051221399561274822396000069522
```

What I want to do is to get the *first portion* in one variable:

```
9702195481, 31201(CCC AGENT)
```

and replace the comma with a semicolon.

And the *second string* starts at the end of the first string and it's 20 characters. So it would return

```
09999051221399561274
```

I have tried `substring`, but I get compiler error.

Any suggestions on how I can accomplish this?

Here's the source xml and xslt file.

[XML and XSLT File](http://xsltransform.net/nbUY4kB/1)

Here' the screen shot how it looks like now and the format I want.

[The format I want Image](http://postimg.org/image/9wy821l0t/)

I would actually prefer this to generate CSV however, my formatting is not correct that's why I stick with HTML.

Comment: You're not telling us what determines where the first string ends and the second one starts.

Comment: I have attached the actual XML file with the XSLT that I'm trying to write. I also attached the format I want as an image. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Please post your code here (within your question). See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to end up with one long string concatenating all your DictionaryEntry/Values, then don't do this:

```
<td>
    <xsl:for-each select="CAudioFile/CRI/PrivateData/PrivateData/DictionaryEntry">
        <xsl:value-of select="Value" />
    </xsl:for-each>
</td>
```

Try instead:

```
<td>
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(CAudioFile/CRI/PrivateData/PrivateData/DictionaryEntry[1]/Value, ',', ';')" />
    <xsl:value-of select="CAudioFile/CRI/PrivateData/PrivateData/DictionaryEntry[2]/Value" />
</td>
```

or perhaps:

```
<td>
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(CAudioFile/CRI/PrivateData/PrivateData/DictionaryEntry[Key='CD1']/Value, ',', ';')" />
    <xsl:value-of select="CAudioFile/CRI/PrivateData/PrivateData/DictionaryEntry[Key='CD2']/Value" />
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

This XPath expression will extract the first part of the string *if* you can consider the `)` to be a delimiter (it doesn't occur anywhere else in your candidate strings):

```
concat(translate(substring-before('9702195481, 31201(CCC ...', ')'),',',';'),')')
```

This one will get the first 20 characters of the second part:

```
substring(substring-after('9702195481, 31201(CCC ...', ')'),1,20)
```

You can use these in your `<xsl:value-of select="">` and place it inside a `<xsl:variable>` to save it in a variable:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="/CAudioFile/CRI/PrivateData/PrivateData/DictionaryEntry">
        <xsl:variable name="first">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(translate(substring-before(., ')'),',',';'),')')" />
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="second">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(substring-after(., ')'),1,20)" />
        </xsl:variable>

        <first-part><xsl:value-of select="$first" /></first-part>
        <second-part><xsl:value-of select="$second" /></second-part>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

Assuming the example string you provided

```
9702195481, 31201(CCC AGENT)09999051221399561274822396000069522
```

is the value of the context node in the `for-each` (for a certain iteration), it will print this:

```
<first-part>9702195481; 31201(CCC AGENT)</first-part>
<second-part>09999051221399561274</second-part>
```

You can verify this transformation in this **[xslt fiddle](http://xsltransform.net/jyyiVhz)**

Comment: I tried the code above, but I'm getting a XSLT compile error when I run my program. If I remove this code, it runs without any errors.

Comment: Sorry. I typed the code in my cell phone (shouldn't do that :D) and some tags were unclosed. I fixed it now.

Comment: It fixed the compiler error. Thank you. But this is the output I'm getting. CD19702195481; 31201(GCG AGENT)))  It added "CD" and two extra parenthesis at the end. And it didn't pick the 20 digit number in the second variable. Any ideas?

Comment: I based the answer on the example you provided, and noted that you can use this *if you can consider the ) to be a delimiter*. If your data has extra `)` it will not work. Edit your question and include a sufficient example showing examples of possible formats for your input data.

Comment: I'm actually using the same string as posted above. There's no 'CD' in front of the number 9702... Also, after debugging the code, there's no value returning in the second variable '<second-part><xsl:value-of select="$second" /></second-part> '

Comment: You are *not* using the same string. Check your data. There is nothing in the code above that adds a `CD` substring.

Comment: You can see here: http://xsltransform.net/jyyiVhz that the transformation for the string you provided works. If it's not working in your real example, your data is not as you described in your question. I suggest you edit your question and include your XML source and other templates of your XSLT stylesheet that are relevant to your question.

Comment: You must check if your `DictionaryEntry` has child elements instead of text. I assumed it contained *text*. If it contains child elements, the text values inside those child elements may be appended to your text string. Show your XML source and we may be able to suggest a solution.

Comment: I added the source XML with XSLT and the output I'm trying to get. Thank you for your help.